# Asp.Net Core supported HttpCaching Nuget Package

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, http-caching

I'm currently working with `WebAPI 2` and considering to upgrade to `ASP.Net Core`.

currently, My http caching is managed by `Strathweb.CacheOutput.WebApi2` and I realized it's not supported by `Asp.Net Core`.

the key features I like about it:

- full control over what is being cached and how
- auto invalidation of Caches whenever a post/put/delete/patch occurs

for the full list of features, `Strathweb.CacheOutput.WebApi2` on github: https://github.com/filipw/Strathweb.CacheOutput

any idea of a corresponding package?

(in the worst case scenario, I'll obviously have to write my own logic...)

**Notes:** I'm aware of `ResponseCacheAttribute` but it lacks the auto invalidation feature

Comment: have you looked into build in caching? https://github.com/aspnet/Caching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ResponseCacheAttribute`](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/performance/caching/response.html) is all about the `Cache-Control` HTTP response header (browser based cache). I think that is not what you are looking for.

You also have [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching`](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/performance/caching/response.html), but at the current version (release 1.0.0) it does not support invalidation on POST/PATCH/DELETE, as you said.

Your options:

- Wait until it is implemented. See [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/ResponseCaching/issues/10)
- Fork and implement yourself. (check the [ResponseCachingContext](https://github.com/aspnet/ResponseCaching/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching/ResponseCachingContext.cs) class)

Comment: Why isn't browser caching what I'm looking for?

Comment: mmm... good question. Actually browser caching can work if your Cache-Control includes the `must-revalidate` directive and you have a server side memory cache. But the ResponseCacheAttribute is not really a cache implementation, currently (1.0.0)  it is only an HTTP header telling the browser - " Hey, dont re-request this for 5 minutes, okay? "

Comment: Which means that cache invalidation is not possible anymore.